# Restar dos fechas que están en forma de cadenas (str)

Tags: python, date

Necesito saber como puedo restar fechas, estoy realizando una aplicación "basica" en la cual necesito restar do fechas ejemplo:

```
(01-03-2019 18:00 - 01-03-2019 19:00) / (412.15 - 417.17)
```

Ambas fechas son cadenas (`str`). La verdad es que estoy bastante confundido como trabajar con fechas y hora en Python. Espero alguien pueda darme el impulso inicial para llevar a cabo esta tarea.

Comment: Hola Bruno, seria bueno que aportaras algo más de información. Por ejemplo ¿Tus fechas de dónde vienen?¿Son cadenas o objetos `datetime`? ¿El resultado de la resta sería en días, horas, segundos, milisegundos, etc?

Comment: tipo cadena, con estos datos lo que necesito es sacar una velocidad en cm/dia. por lo que 412.15 seria deformacion 1 - 417.17 deformacion2 lo que da (tiempo 2 - tiempo 1) / (deformacion 1 - deformacion 2) el resultado expresarlo en cm/dia

Answer (score 4):

Lo primero es parsear esa cadena a algo que represente una fecha y se pueda operar. La clase [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) nos permite representar la combinación de fecha + hora que necesitamos.

Para pasar de una cadena que representa una fecha a un objeto `datetime.datetime` basta con usar el método [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Como primer argumento recibe la cadena en sí, como segundo argumento recibe otra cadena que representa el formato según lo especificado en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

fecha_cad1 = '01-03-2019 18:00'
fecha_cad2 = '01-03-2019 19:00'
fecha1 = datetime.strptime(fecha_cad1, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
fecha2 = datetime.strptime(fecha_cad2, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

Cuando tenemos las dos fechas como sendos objetos `datetime.datetime` basta con restarlos, lo que resulta en un objeto [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

> ```
> >>> res = fecha2 - fecha1
> >>> res
> datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
> ```

Si queremos obtener la diferencia en un intervalo determinado solo hay que dividir por otro `timedelta` que represente la medida que queremos:

```
microsegundos = res / timedelta(microseconds=1)
segundos = res / timedelta(seconds=1)    # Equivalente a res.total_seconds()
horas = res / timedelta(hours=1)
dias = res / timedelta(days=1)
```

Todo junto, si queremos obtener la diferencia en días de tus dos fechas:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

fecha_cad1 = '01-03-2019 18:00'
fecha_cad2 = '01-03-2019 19:00'
fecha1 = datetime.strptime(fecha_cad1, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
fecha2 = datetime.strptime(fecha_cad2, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

dias = (fecha2 - fecha1) / timedelta(days=1)
print(dias)  # 0.041666666666666664
```

Podemos obtener el atributo `days` de `timedelta`, `dias = (fecha2 - fecha1).days`, pero en este caso retorna la diferencia de dias completos, en el caso anterior 0.

Comment: Estando a punto de publicar mi respuesta, llegas con esta parecida a lo que iba a poner.

Answer (score 3):

Si deseas hacer operaciones con fechas seria primero importar datetime,date,timedelta. Un ejemplo de como realizarse.

```
>>> #asigna fecha actual
>>> hoy=date.today()
>>> #suma a fecha actual 1 dia
>>> mañana=hoy+timedelta(days=1)
>>> #diferencia
>>> diferencia_en_dias=mañana-hoy
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]