# Cálculo de fechas en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, date

¡Buenas!

Actualmente tengo la siguiente función:

```
def between_days():
    print ('=== Between days ===')
    """
    dateExpiration: date expiration of old service
    type: int
    dateElimination: date elimination of old service
    type: int
    """

    print("Date of expiration service: ")
    yearOld = int(input("Year "))
    monthOld = int(input("Month "))
    dayOld = int(input("Day "))

    dateExpiration = date(yearOld, monthOld, dayOld)

    print("Date of deleted service: ")

    yearNew = int(input("Year "))
    monthNew = int(input("Month "))
    dayNew = int(input("Day "))

    dateElimination = date(yearNew, monthNew, dayNew)

    result = (dateElimination - dateExpiration).days

    return print(result, " days of difference.")
```

Básicamente lo que hace es solicitar al usuario dos fechas para calcular la diferencia de días solicitándole año, mes y día por separado. 
El caso es que llevo dándole vueltas un par de semanas y no consigo sacar como hacer para que lo solicite directamente con el formato de date, es decir, YYYY/MM/DD y directamente lo calcule sin solicitar los datos por separado.
Recurro ya a vosotros por pura desesperación.
¿Se os ocurre como podría ser?

Muchísimas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Hola Jesús, creo que puede ser un duplicado de [Restar dos fechas que están en forma de cadenas (str)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/259242/15089]). En mi respuesta tienes además como convertir una cadena a objeto `datetime` para que el usuario pueda ingresar con el formato que quieras. En tu caso el formato para `strptime` sería `"%Y/%m/%d"`. Es decir, algo así `str_date = input("Ingrese la fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd: ")`; `date_exp = datetime.strptime(str_date, "%Y/%m/%d")`, luego restas ambas fechas. No obstante, si aún así sigues con problemas edita la pregunta o comenta. Un saludo.

Comment: Cierto, no había visto ese post. Voy a probarlo por que seguramente sea lo que estaba buscando. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, si tienes alguna duda comenta. Podrías parsear tu mismo la cadena usando `str.split` o expresiones regulares. Por ejemplo,  `año, mes, dia = (int(n) for n in str_date.split("/"))`. No obstante `datetime.strptime` ya lo tenemos disponible y es más robusto. En cuanto a la resta, dado que siempre en tu caso van a ser días completos, lo puedes hacer exactamente como lo haces ahora (`(dateElimination - dateExpiration).days`,). Si quisieras por lo que sea pasar de un objeto  `datetime` a `date` solo tienes que  hacer `date_obj = datetime_obj.date()`, aunque en tu caso es innecesario.