# Marcar hora entrada de trabajadores en Python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Estoy haciendo un programa que permita marcar las asistencias de unos profesores, pero estoy estancado acá.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time

trabajadores = [77500025, 72863971,40315348]


dni = int(input("Ingresa tu dni: "))
h = input("\nIngrese Hora de Ingreso: ")
m = input("\nIngrese Minutos de Ingreso: ")

hora_entrada = datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00', '%H:%M')

for i in range(len(trabajadores)):
    if dni == (trabajadores[i]):
        print(dni)
        ahora = datetime.datetime.now()
        hora_marca = ahora.strftime("%X")
        print(hora_marca)

        s= '08:00:00'
        y = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%X:%M:%S')
        print(y)
```

Al principio mi idea era realizar la variable trabajadores con una base de datos sqlite3, pero no encontré por ningún lado cómo trabajar los datos de la manera que quiero hacerlo con este programa, (captar hora de entrada y compararlo con una determinada hora de salida si la resta de estos es menor a 8 horas, si la validación es correcta aplicar un descuento)

Comment: Hola Diego, no termino de entender cual es tu problema concreto exactamente. Puedes restar dos objetos datetime sin problemas, lo cual te genera un objeto timedelta con la diferencia de tiempo: [Restar dos fechas que están en formato de cadena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/259242/15089).

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que quiero que un trabajador al poner su Dni, el sistema capture su hora de entrada y que lo reste digamos con la hora de salida y si es menor a 8 horas, que lo marque como tardanza,

Comment: La hora entrada sería entonces la del sistema cuando el usuario ingresa su dni y quisieras que se obtuviera automáticamente ¿no? ¿La hora e salida también debe obtenerse igual? ¿O sería una hora prefijada fija?

Comment: Una hora prefijada, pero como haria al siguiente dia? tendria que actualizar constantemente esa hora?,

Comment: intente hacerlo con  una base de datos que maneje los datos de los traBajadores pero no encontre forma de realizar eso que pongo arriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te han comentado, lo único que debes hacer es restar dos horas `datetime.datetime` para obtener un `datetime.timedelta` y poder trabajar con la diferencia. No sé por qué manejas 3 horas (´hora_entrada´, ´ahora´ y ´s´), cuando sólo se deben manejar 2.

Otro problema es que sólo introduces la hora sin la fecha. Esto significa que cuando ingresas las 09:00 en realidad manejas las 09:00 de el 1 enero de 1901

Tampoco entiendo por qué utilizas la directiva `%X` en ese contexto.

Con una hora prefijada de salida, algo que podría funcionar sería:

```
import datetime

trabajadores = [1, 72863971,40315348]

def control_tiempos():
    dni = int(input("Ingresa tu dni: "))

    if dni not in trabajadores:
        print("El DNI ingresado no está en la base de datos. Ingréselo de nuevo")
        control_tiempos()

    hoy = datetime.datetime.today()

    # Establecemos la hora de entrada con los datos de hoy y la hora de
    # entrada. En este caso hoy a las 17:00. Mañana será mañana a las
    # 17:00 y así sucesivamente
    hora_entrada = datetime.datetime(hoy.year, hoy.month, hoy.day, 17, 0)

    for i in range(len(trabajadores)):
        if dni == (trabajadores[i]):
            print(dni)
            # La hora de salida se establecerá en el momento de introducir el DNI
            hora_salida = datetime.datetime.now()
            diferencia = hora_salida - hora_entrada
            if diferencia.seconds < 28800: # 28800 segundos == 8 horas
                print("El trabajador con dni: %d ha trabajado menos de 8 horas" % dni)


control_tiempos()
```

Comment: gracias @arg0s, entiendo que es con date, pero existe una manera de automatizar eso? osea por ejemplo en cuanto yo ponga mi dni marque automaticamente a que hor entre, y asimismo automatice la hora de salida, porque con el codigo que haz puesto tengo que cambiarlo cada dia verdad?

Comment: Evidentemente era un ejemplo. Se puede sustuiir `hora_entrada` por la fecha de "hoy" con una hora prefijada (por ejemplo las 17:00) y `hora_salida` por `datetime.datetime.now()` (la fecha y hora actual en el momento de ingresar el dni). Editado y corregida la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Muchisimas Gracias @arg0s, lo modifique a los requerimientos que necesitaba(marcar la hora de entrada, y la de salida prefijada automaticamente) y asi quedo la función control de tiempo.

```
import datetime

trabajadores = [1, 72863971,40315348]

def control_tiempos():
    dni = int(input("Ingresa tu dni: "))

    if dni not in trabajadores:
        print("El DNI ingresado no está en la base de datos. Ingréselo de nuevo")
        control_tiempos()

    hoy = datetime.datetime.today()

    # Establecemos la hora de entrada con los datos de hoy y la hora de
    # entrada. En este caso hoy a las 17:00. Mañana será mañana a las
    # 17:00 y así sucesivamente
    hora_entrada = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(hora_entrada)


    for i in range(len(trabajadores)):
        if dni == (trabajadores[i]):

            print(dni)
            # La hora de salida se establecerá en el momento de introducir el DNI
            hora_salida = datetime.datetime(hoy.year, hoy.month, hoy.day, 17, 0)
            diferencia = hora_salida - hora_entrada
            if diferencia.seconds < 28800: # 28800 segundos == 8 horas
                print("El trabajador con dni: %d ha trabajado menos de 8 horas" % dni)
            else:
                print("Haz llegado temprano")

control_tiempos()
```